# Determine if a matrix is unimodular

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra, algorithms, determinants

Is deciding if an integer square matrix has determinant $\pm 1$ faster that calculating the determinant of the matrix?

Comment: could you expand a bit on how this question is similar to detection of unimodularity, where *every* sub-determinant has to be in $\lbrace 0,\pm 1\rbrace$

Comment: Sorry I misread the answers paper, their definition of unimodular used in Theorem 1 is more general to cover non-square matrices. I'll edit the question and remove the reference.

Comment: assuming unit costs for arithmetic operations, probably the decision problem is as hard as the computation. for example, take a diagonal matrix....

Comment: I don't know if this is 'faster', but consider the sequence of elementary operations which reduces a square integer matrix $A$ to it's Smith Normal form. We have an algorithm which determines the elementary divisors of $A$, and if any of these elementary divisors is $\neq \pm 1$, then we'll know $A$ is not unimodular. Any step in the reduction implements a euclidean algorithm to compute gcd's. That is, we are constantly reducing rows and colomns. If $A$ is unimodular, then we'll have computed all its elementary divisors, and their product is of course $detA$. So reducing $A$ to its Jordan  

Comment: normal form, either $A$ is not unimodular and we shall eventually determine an elementary divisor $\neq \pm 1$ (which of course, may only occur at the last step), or we determine all of its elementary divisors to be $\pm 1$, and then we've just computed the determinant. So maybe the right question is simply whether or not computing the Smith normal form is faster than computing the determinant. 

Comment: And on this last point: for a very large matrix, I would much rather face the task of finding its Smith normal form than computing it's determinant. So I think computing smith normal form is faster than computing the determinant (via usual Laplace expansion). Of course, I would only do this after checking that every colomn and row of my matrix was primitive, ie. gcd of each colomn and row is 1.  

Comment: @Suvrit. The decision problem for a diagonal matrix (or upper triangular) INTEGRAL matrix is easy: just check every diagonal is $\pm 1$. 

Comment: @J.Martel: I was thinking in terms of matrices with rational entries instead of integers; btw., computation of determinant is essentially an $O(n^3)$ procedure (Gaussian elimination); I guess the SNF is not much faster, if at all?

Comment: In fact, thanks to LU decomposition, computing the determinant is at least as fast as computing a matrix product. So we can compute the determinant exactly in $O(n^{2.376}). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Theoretical_complexity.

Similarly, in Storjohann's paper "Near Optimal Algorithms for Computing Smith Normal Forms of Integer Matrices" he shows a similar inequality. That is, for an integer square matrix, computing its SNF is at least as fast as computing a matrix product.

Comment: So the conclusion is...?

Answer (score 2):

From [Santha and Tan, "Verifying the determinant in parallel"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00001596):

> "for the determinant, there doesn't seem to be a simpler way to verify it than the computation itself."

Other notes:

Matrix multiplication, inversion, and determinant-finding are all equally complex. I will quote from [Kaltofen and Villard, "Computing the sign or the value of the determinant of an integer matrix, a complexity survey"](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kaltofen/bibliography/02/KaVi02.pdf):

> In algebraic complexity—i.e. when counting the number of operations in
>   an abstract domain—we refer to Strassen [52] and Bunch & Hopcroft [13]
>   for the reduction of the problem of computing the determinant to
>   matrix multiplication. Conversely, Strassen [53] and Bunch & Hopcroft
>   [13] reduce matrix multiplication to matrix inversion, and Baur &
>   Strassen reduce matrix inversion to computing the determinant [7]

Since unimodularity amounts to invertibility, your question is equivalent to "is determining invertibility easier than actually computing the inverse (if it exists)?"